# How to write a zipfile to another location

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I have some Python code that I have written that creates a zip file but it writes the file to the location where the Python script is located versus the folder I need it to be written to.  How do I structure my code to make it write to the location I need it to?

```
def get_all_file_paths(directory):
    file_paths = []

    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)
        return file_paths

for root, subdirectories, files in os.walk(src):
    if root != src + 'Errors':
        for subdirectory in subdirectories:
            if subdirectory != 'A' and subdirectory != 'B' and subdirectory != 'C':
                print(subdirectory)
                folderName = subdirectory
                print('The folder name is', folderName)
                print(os.path.join(root, subdirectory))
                filePath = os.path.join(root, subdirectory)
                file_paths = get_all_file_paths(filePath)

                print('Following files will be zipped: ')
                for file_name in file_paths:
                    print(file_name)
                
                with ZipFile(folderName +'.zip', 'w') as zip:
                    for file in file_paths:
                        zip.write(file, os.path.relpath(file, root))
                    zip.close()
                
                print('All files zipped successfully!')
```

Comment: you're performing a double os.walk you'll probably end up with a lot of duplicated files in your archive.

Comment: `folderName = subdirectory` this is a relative path. join with `root`

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre!  Referencing the filePath variable instead of the folderName variable saved it where I needed it to.  Is that what you are recommending?

Also, where am I performing the double os.walk?  I'm not getting any duplicates in my archive zip file.